# If $a²+b²=7ab$ where a and b are positive then show that $log(1/3(a+b))=1/2(log a +log b)$

Tags: logarithms

Welcome sir, to the content of my question, please  help me:

If $a²+b²=7ab$ where a and b are positive then show that $log(1/3(a+b))=1/2(log a +log b)$

Comment: Could you please provide some context for this question, and your thoughts on it, or progress so far?

Comment: Thank you Old John. For the question I tried to find log(a²+b²) without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a^2+b^2=7ab$ follows $(a+b)^2=9ab$   or $a+b=3 (ab)^{\frac{1}{2}}$  or $\frac{1}{3}(a+b)= (ab)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$ Thus
$$
\log\frac{1}{3}(a+b)= \log (ab)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}(\log a+\log b).
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab,$  we have $(a+b)^2=9ab$

Apply Sum of Logarithms formula ($(2)$ of [this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Laws_of_Logarithms))

Comment: Thank you so much sir. The greatest source of happiness is the ability to be grateful at all times.

Comment: (a+b)²=9ab <br>
log 1/3(a+b)= log 1/3 x 9ab <br>
log1/3(a+b)= .... Struggle!

Comment: @user115735, why struggle?

Comment: I find log1/3(a+b)=log3ab but how is log 3ab equal to 1/2 (log a + log b)